# regex include main page visits from one keyword

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I got a lot of visits to my site main page from different keywords. Examples of format might be as following:

```
/?keyword= train hard
```

`/`

`/?keyword=`
 
etc., etc.

To be able to sum up all visits to my main page despite from the keyword, I wanted to use a Regex like `^/$`. However, that didn't work out. What RegEx should I apply to get the proper result?

What RegEx should I apply to see other sections of my website in a similar way? E.g.

```
/booking?keyword= or /section?keyword=any ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For main page you can try: `^\/(?:\?keyword=.*)?$`

Look here for example: https://regex101.com/r/5uCFun/2

For other pages similarly: `^\/booking(?:\?keyword=.*)?$`

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/1dAaHL/2